# is there a way to get boids to fly at max air speed WITHOUT locking them to a altitude?

Tags: animation, particles, boids

im trying to get a reaction from boids that involves overshooting a moving goal
setting min airspeed to max gives me that overshooting behavior.
but also seems the boids cant fly up or down to meet their goal anymore

is this just a limitation of blenders implementation of boids?
cause it sorta sucks if so
espcially for non natural flocking behaviors (think syfi stuff)

im guessing the boid sims flight is based on actual in atmosphere flight
so speed = lift = flight
so going max speed all the time = 100% lift = never going down or up?

id post an example blend but its 30MB and the problem is simple enough to reproduce if you know your way around the particle system

example blend file (let me know if it actual works since im not sure what i did to shave off 15mbs)
[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question. A simple example blend file demonstrating  just that issue should limit the size.

Comment: You should be able to create a toy version of your problem with a small file-size? ... at least, please include a screen-grab of the 'Movement' settings of your Boid system.

Comment: i think i got it? i messed with some settings for the particle cache and that got it down to 15mb. uploading